# Countdown Timer, setInterval within setInterval?

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval

I'm sort of a JS newbie here, and working on a countdown timer that begins after a given time period.  Basically, a clock starts when the user clicks a button, and a second clock starts when that first timer runs out.  I understand that "setInterval" is the best way accomplish this.  The main problem I am facing is that the second timer, although it pops up on the screen, does not start counting down.  I believe this is because I am trying to run a setInterval within a setInterval, but not sure.  Also the lead timer "beeps" at 1 instead of 0.  Below is the code.  The countdown function begins when a form button is pressed.

```
<script>

function countdown(form){
    lead = form.leadseconds.value;
    cd = form.cdseconds.value;
    startLeader = setInterval(leadtimer, 1000);
}

function leadtimer(){
    if (lead > 0){
        document.getElementById("leadtime").innerHTML = lead;
        lead--;
    }
    if (lead == 0){
        document.getElementById("leadtime").innerHTML = "beep";
        startTimer = setInterval(cdtimer, 1000);
        clearInterval(startLeader);
    }

}

function cdtimer(){
    if (cd > 0){
        document.getElementById("cdtime").innerHTML = cd;
        lead--;
    }
    if (cd == 0){
        document.getElementById("cdtime").innerHTML = "beepbeep";
        clearInterval(startTimer);
    }

}

 </script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Why `if (cd > 0) { lead--; }`?

Comment: Have you declared global vars somewhere (`lead`, `cd`, `startLeader`, `startTimer`)?

Comment: You got it!  Was decrementing the wrong variable in the cdtimer function.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem: You're getting the "beep" one second early because when `lead` gets to `1`, the first if (`lead > 0`) happens as usual, and `lead` is decremented. `lead` now equals zero. Then execution moves along to the second if. Since you just decremented `lead` to zero, that if body gets executed as well. You want an "else if", so only one of the two blocks ever executes. Like so:

```
if ( lead > 0 ) {
    //  Do stuff. 
    lead--;
} else if ( lead == 0 ) {
    //  Do other stuff. 
}
```

Secondly, in `cdtimer()`, you're decrementing `lead`: `lead--;`. I'd guess that was a mistake that crept in when you copied the first timer function and renamed it. At least, that's how I always end up with code like that.

Also, of course, you want to use the `else if` in `cdtimer()` as well.